# Environmental Variables not working even though it is defined in .env.local file?

Tags: next.js, xata

I have defined my keys in `.env.local` but still while calling it `process.env.API_KEY` it doesn't work as expected.

```
API_KEY=xx_xxxxxxxxxxxx

DATABASE_URL=https://xxxxx/db/main
```

**Code:**

```
export const xata = new BaseClient({
  apiKey: process.env.API_KEY,
  databaseURL: process.env.DATABASE_URL
});
```

**Folder Structure:**

```
Project
     - pages
     - public
     - .env.local
     - helper (file that needs api key)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Next.JS, when you add [environment variables](https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/environment-variables#loading-environment-variables) in your `.env.*` files whose name don't start with
`NEXT_PUBLIC_` , they are only available to the Node.Js environment. So you can access them in `API Routes` and `data fetching methods like GetServerSideProps etc.`

If you want to access variables in [client browser](https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/environment-variables#exposing-environment-variables-to-the-browser) you have to append `NEXT_PUBLIC_`.

Your file becomes :

```
NEXT_PUBLIC_API_KEY=xx_xxxxxxxxxxxx

NEXT_PUBLIC_DATABASE_URL=https://xxxxx/db/main
```

Comment: Accessing Variables in the client browser via `NEXT_PUBLIC_`, will the keys be vulnerable ?

Comment: Yes. The way to get around that is using your custom `API Routes`. A link https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2021/12/protect-api-key-production-nextjs-api-route/

Comment: Just check, `NEXT_PUBLIC_API_KEY` also doesn't work. 
Show NEXT_PUBLIC_API_KEY undefined

Comment: Regarding security : You do not use `NEXT_PUBLIC_` but also do not directly call any API which requires the key. Instead you call your Next.js API Routes and they interact with the API using the API Key. This works because as mentioned in the answer Node.js env including the API Routes have access to keys even without `NEXT_PUBLIC_`.

Comment: How are you accessing the key?

Comment: Sry, my bad. Works.